# MonoTouch: Can't get app to run in high-res (640x960) on simulator or phone

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

I'm developing a MonoTouch app and whenever I run it on either the iPhone 4 or the simulator, it runs at 320x480 rather than 640x960. I've gone into the simulator and chosen Hardware->Device->iPhone (Retina), but the simulator still seems to be pixel-doubled and UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds is still 320x480.

My app is a Universal Application and it runs on the iPad (both device and simulator) at the proper resolution.

Is there some setting I'm missing that tells the device that my app wants to run at the higher resolution if it's available on the device?

Comment: Do you have a high-res set of PNGs in line with your normal PNGs?If so, how are they named?

Answer (score 1):

Since hi-res is a feature of newer versions of iOS, make sure that you set the SDK in your project settings to 4.x, and not the older 3.x setting.

Additionally, there are many other details that you will want to take into account, I wrote a blog post on what I did to make my open source TweetStation support the Retina Display:

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Jul-20-2.html

Comment: Great article, thanks. I've got my app setting ContentScaleFactor=2 now, and that works for me on the retina display. The problem that I have now is that on the iPad and iPhones without retina, I want ContentScaleFactor=1 so my renderbuffer matches the resolution of the device. What's the best way to determine at startup time if I should set ContentScaleFactor=2? Or to rephrase it, how can I ask iOS, "What is the resolution of the device I'm on, in pixels (not points)?"

Comment: UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale will give you that number 1.0 or 2.0